# Load PostgreSQL data into BigQuery using a Cloud Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Tried to implement the Cloud data-flow task, loading data from PostgreSQL database table to Google Cloud Bigquery table help of below URL document. When executing data-flow job got issue. Refer the screen shot [1].

URL: [Approach 2:ETL into BigQuery with Cloud Dataflow][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Dataflow supports 2.x version of SDK. Since this code is with version 1.x so got this generic issue when run the dataflow pipeline in Google Cloud. After migrate it to 2.x version able to run the code successfully.